# mypy: Class signature updated in decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I've got a problem with mypy. My code:

```
def response_schema(default_response_cls: Type[BaseModel]):
    def wraps_source(source_cls: Type[BaseModel]):
        def get_response_func(self: BaseModel, **kwargs):
            return get_response(self, response_cls=default_response_cls, **kwargs)

        source_cls.get_response = get_response_func
        return source_cls

    return wraps_source
```

This decorator flags pydantic schema with another by decorator and fill it if get_response func is called
and mypy says

```
Item "AnySourceSchema" of "Optional[AnySourceSchema]" has no attribute "get_response"
```

Can you help me to update class signature with that func? I tried use TypeVar - doesn't help

Comment: where is the `get_response` on line 4 defined? If this is acting like a typical decorator and is wrapping the `get_response` already on the class, could lines 3-6 be replaced with `source_cls.get_response = functools.partial(source_cls.get_response, response_cls=default_response_cls)`?

Comment: As a static type checker, mpyp won't detect dynamically added attributes. You can indicate a custom return type for the decorator which includes the function in question.

Comment: @a_guest I think, it's a good choice! thank you! write answer and I will flag it as the right one!

Comment: Without seeing the context in which this is applied it's difficult to make a concrete suggestion. I don't see why you need this decorator anyway. It looks more like you want a base class with `def get_response(self): raise NotImplementedError` and then make concrete subclasses that override this method. Would that work?

Comment: @a_guest it works like that right now, but some classes don't have this decorator but inherited from the same super class